# SQL query enigma

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
ID|Name|Issue|Location   
1 |01  |A    |.....  
2 |01  |B    |.....    
3 |02  |A    |.....  
4 |02  |B    |.....  
5 |02  |C    |.....   
6 |03  |A    |.....
```

I want query that will return the id,name,issue,location for the max(issue) for each
like :

```
 2 |01  |B    |.....  
 5 |02  |C    |.....  
 6 |03  |A    |.....
```

Thanks

Comment: "I want query that will return the id,name,issue,location for the max(issue) for each" - each what? Each ID? Each Name? Each location? (Presumably not each record?)

Answer (score 4):

```
select t.* 
from tab t 
join (
    select name, max(issue) as issue
    from tab
    group by name
) t1 on t.name = t1.name and t.issue = t1.issue
```